# Parser data with format json in react

Tags: json, reactjs, parsing, axios

I am new to react.js and I am trying to display data in JSON format in a table. So what I did is:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
class TableUser extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state = {
      libelle_produit: ''
    };
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    axios
      .get('admin/prdtId/')
      .then(({ data })=> {
        this.setState({ 
          libelle_produit: data.libelle_produit
        });
      })
      .catch((err)=> {})
  }     
  render() {
      return <div>
      <p>{ this.state.libelle_produit }</p>
    </div>;
  }
}

export default TableUser;
```

i'd want to be able to access the libelle product of each component and print those on the website

[{"libelle_produit":"test produit"}]

Thanks

Comment: Can you share what `data.libelle_produit` is returning currently?

Comment: What do you mean by recover?

Comment: recover= recuperate recuperate libelle_produit from this format json [{"libelle_produit":"test produit"}]

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    { this.state.libelle_produit != '' ? this.state.libelle_produit.map( (item, index) => 
        <p>{libelle_produit</p>
    }
</div>
```

If the array isnt empty, then loop trough the array and return a p tag with the title of the libelle_produit

Comment: you will need to provide a key to your <p>

Comment: @Nath true, just do key={index}